# How to find the original directory when running parent npm script from subdirectory?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a fairly standard web application structure which is using npm to execute some node.js test scripts.  In addition, npm allows you to execute the parent package scripts from a subdirectory.

As an example:

```
|-- my-app
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- test-script.js
|   |-- component-one
|   |   |-- test-one.spec.js
|   |-- component-two
|   |   |-- test-two.spec.js

> /my-app/component-one: npm run test
# Runs test-script.js as specified in root package's scripts
```

I would like to be able to determine the original subfolder that I run the scripts from.  However, I haven't been able to find a way to access that directory. Both `process.cwd()` and `__dirname` are returning the parent level directory location of the script (*my-app* in the example).

My primary use case is to filter the tests to only run ones in the current sub directory, so adding individual scripts to run for each subdirectory isn't practical.

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: I am using node 10.16.0 and npm 6.9.0

Comment: how are you calling `process.cwd()` exactly? that should return the current working directory.

Comment: also if you could post the test script, that would help

Comment: @Yeysides The script really isn't that important.  It can just be a call to  ```console.log(process.cwd())``` and see that it's not returning the subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [npm docs:](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

> Scripts are run from the root of the module, regardless of what your
>   current working directory is when you call npm run. If you want your
>   script to use different behavior based on what subdirectory you’re in,
>   you can use the `INIT_CWD` environment variable, which holds the full
>   path you were in when you ran npm run.

Docs from the [pull request:](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/12356/files)

`npm run` adds current working directory to `INIT_CWD`. You can run scripts in subdirectory of project. For example, you want to run babel in specific subdirectory. You should write:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel $INIT_CWD/src -d $INIT_CWD/lib"
}
```

or you can write:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "cd $INIT_CWD && babel src -d lib"
}
```

Now, you can run the script, `npm run build` in any subdirectory you want to compile JavaScript. In your case, you may need to pass the cwd as an argument to the script and override the `INIT_CWD` var.